# Python sqlalchemy completely terminate session correctly

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I apologize if this has been answered. I've searched repeatedly over years and have yet to find an adequate solution to actually terminate a session on a postgresql 13 server made by my python scripts. A simple example:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# Create engine
connection_string = v.connection_string
engine = create_engine(connection_string)

# Create a Session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

try:
    # Use session connection
    with session.connection() as connection:
        connection.execute(text('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 
        interim_schema.location;'))
    session.commit()

except SQLAlchemyError as e:
    print(f"Error occurred while executing SQL commands: {e}")
    session.rollback()
finally:
    session.close()
```

My understanding is this should completely close the session, but it doesn't.

I've tried engine.dispose() but that just resets the connection pool. I've tried the recommended session as explained above which also does not terminate the session. I expect the database connection to vanish on the postresql server side.

Comment: How do you conclude it doesn't close the session? (also, please fix the indentation)

Comment: Thanks. for the heads up on indentation. 

I'm doing this locally before deploying to GCP and I can see the connection is still active on my local postgresql.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how you see the connection still active on your local postgresql server?

Comment: You need to close all sessions, then call `engine.dispose()`.  Calling `engine.dispose()` while sessions are open may result in connections being left open. See [engine disposal](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#engine-disposal).

Answer (score 0):

It's just an example. I suggest you to read more about `context manager` and `decorators` in python. It's really helpful.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base, sessionmaker


class SqlAlchemy:
    def __init__(self, database_url: str):
        self.engine = create_engine(database_url, echo=False)
        self.session = sessionmaker(self.engine)
        self.base = declarative_base()


@contextmanager
def in_transaction(session) -> Session:
    session = session()
    session.begin()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except BaseException:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()


db = SqlAlchemy('your database url')


def db_session(db):
    with in_transaction(db.session) as session:
        yield session
        
        
# example function where you need session
@db_session
def my_function(session):
    session.execute('SQL for example:)')
```

Comment: @clayton_wonders does it make sense?